# Искус и искусство

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Интересно, почему слова "искушение" и "искусство" родственные? Вроде как по смыслу ничего общего. И еще интересует слово "искусный": оно тоже происходит от слова "искус", так ведь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из газеты "Русский язык"

В древнерусском языке видовая пара глаголов кусити – искусити имела значение «испытывать – испытать». И это логично: вспомним, как младенец испытывает новую игрушку... Им этимологически родственно существительное искус, имевшее два значения: «тяжелое испытание» и «умение, мастерство» (как результат тяжелых испытаний). Именно от него во втором значении и были образованы слова, правописание которых мы выясняем.

В результате прибавления суффикса прилагательного -н- получилось слово искусный. С помощью суффикса отвлеченного существительного -ств- появилось искусство (аналогично герой – геройство, мастер – мастерство), а уже от него было произведено прилагательное искусственный.

```
КУСИТИ ––> ИСКУСИТИ ––> ИСКУ`С

ИСКУ`С + СТВ = ИСКУССТВО,
ИСКУССТВЕННЫЙ

ИСКУ`С + Н = ИСКУСНЫЙ
```

Здесь]1

Искушение - тоже образовано от глагола *искусить*  (искушать) суффиксальным способом (суффикс -ениj-)